# Why won't Windows allow me to upgrade pip?

Tags: python

While trying to create a Bot for Discord i ran across a problem with Python's pip, since it says I have to upgrade from version 7.1.2 to version 9.0.1, but when I imput the command all it does is say i need to update but it just won't let me.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    Collecting pip
      Using cached pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
        root=options.root_path,
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 640, in install
        requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 673, in uninstall
        for path in pip.wheel.uninstallation_paths(dist):
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 512, in unique
        for item in fn(*args, **kw):
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 531, in uninstallation_paths
        r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1619, in get_metadata_lines
        return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
      File "C:\Users\JoséMiguel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1616, in get_metadata
        return self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name)).decode("utf-8")
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 22368: invalid continuation byte
    You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
    You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It does the same every time I run the command, even if I run CMD on Admin.

I have downloaded the latest pip version from the website itself (**pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl**) and **get-pip.py**, but all it does when I run it is the same as the Command Prompt.

What I use is: `Windows 10` and `Python 3.5.2`

Comment: I noticed that older `pip` versions (<8) are having troubles with non-ASCII characters in the path. Like the é in your user name and home folder path.

Comment: I'm almost sure that is your folder name the problem: "JoséMiguel".
I would try to rename it using just  ASCII characters.